# Angular 6 dynamic template reference variable

Tags: angular, angular6

I have two users from which I need to take input and save partially, Here when I am chaging anything inside one child component both save buttons are enabled.
How I can fix it?

Child Component

```
<div [ngModelGroup]="user" #fieldset="ngModelGroup">
  <input name="first" [ngModel]="user.first" minlength="2">
  <input name="last" [ngModel]="user.last" required>

  <button [disabled]="fieldset.pristine||fieldset.invalid">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

Parent Component

```
<form>
  <child-component [user]="object1"></child-component>
  <child-component [user]="object2"></child-component>
</form>
```

Is it possible to template reference variable dynamic

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] reproducing your issue, as it is **totally unclear** right now.

Comment: you have only one form. You should try having two form groups and declare them accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at the Angular documentation for more details on the different approaches: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview. I personally like Reactive Forms.

Comment: How is it that you're not getting the error *No provider for ControlContainer*, see this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-so-54129975) I've created with your code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @benshabatnoam you can check it here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-so-54129975-wfkqii

Comment: @trichetriche Please check it here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-so-54129975-wfkqii

Comment: My problem is resolved : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-so-54129975-wfkqii

Comment: Nice! why don't you answer your question with your solution so others will know? I'll be the first one to up vote you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided the unique "ngModelGroup" for each child and my problem is resolved now

Parent.component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <child-component [formGroupName]="'user1'" [user]="object1"></child-component>
  <child-component [formGroupName]="'user2'" [user]="object2"></child-component>
</form>
<pre>{{f.value|json}} </pre>
```

Child.component.html

```
<div [ngModelGroup]="formGroupName" #fieldset="ngModelGroup">
    <input name="first" [ngModel]="user.first" minlength="2">
    <input name="last" [ngModel]="user.last" required>
    <button [disabled]="fieldset.pristine||fieldset.invalid">
    Save
    </button> 
</div>
```

Child.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer,  FormGroup,  NgForm  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]

})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @Input() formGroupName : string;
  @Input() user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Working StackBlitz Link: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-so-54129975-txntzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

**Note**: Thanks *benshabatnoam* for your efforts.

> Parent-Component CODE

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  users = [
    {first: 'first user first', last: 'first user last'},
    {first: 'second user first', last: 'second user last'}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

> Parent-Component HTML

```
// You don't have to iterate, you can have two or more if you like.
// <child-component [user]="users[0]"></child-component>
// <child-component [user]="users[1]"></child-component>

<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
  <child-component [user]="user"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

> Child-Component CODE

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @Input() user;

  onSubmit(form){ 
    if(form.invalid){
      // Do stuff...
    }
  }
}
```

> Child-Component HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)" #myForm="ngForm">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.first" name="first" minlength="2">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.last" name="last" required>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
    Save
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: In my case Parent component is also a form

Comment: You can nest forms. How would you like it to work with the parent as a form?